7 fixed columns with horizontal scroll in complex data table
I have been trying to define the UX of a complex data table that needs to have the first 6-7 columns fixed followed by infinite weekly data columns. The weekly data columns need to have a horizontal scroll. This is the constraint. After much discussion with the team, the data of the first 6-7 columns need to remain fixed.
I have tried researching best practices for this scenario and could come up with the following solutions -

Have a drag mechanism that lets users see more weekly column data by dragging the first 7 columns to 2 columns and the weekly data is shown through a horizontal scroll as suggested on numerous posts on datatable.net

Have a card view that shows weekly data for a particular row highlighted. See this example:




Just have a scroll option written on top as shown here - https://docs.airdev.co/canvas/v/4.2/canvas-library/blocks/infinite-columns-horizontal-scroll-data-table-with-fixed-first-column

Another example that i think is the best but this will have infinite horizontal scroll:



Has anyone come across a similar scenario? The maximum I could find was 2 fixed columns scenario on the internet.
Some other info that might help you answer -

After user research, the 7 columns data need to shown as users need to see it.
I am trying to prepare multiple options based on this and again go for user testing to see which option is more friendly and helps solve their needs.

Thanks.
Edit: I also tried finding books (not articles) on data table UX design but couldn't find a dedicated one that addresses complex UX/UI patterns.

Overwhelming data is difficult to tackle. One way could be breaking down the data into chunks to show the user in bits.
Option 2 looks reasonable. We handled similar situation and the strategy we took forward was that

Show the identifiable data/important data upfront.
Use Bubble text box or in this case a card dedicated to show more data related to the row.

Using card approach might crack open friction if user is checking each row for longer time which could be noise on the screen.
